# why is devart DefaultValue attribute not working on version 9.7

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, devart

We're using Devart dotConnect for oracle with Entitiy Framework.

We've been using the solution described [here](https://blog.devart.com/set-identity-and-computed-properties-in-entity-framework-without-triggers.html) to generate IDs with sequences and all worked well, untill we upgraded to devart 9.7

It looks as if the DefaultValue is being ignored.
For Example, if I look in the DBMonitor I see the insert command without the seq_name.nextval.

The strange thing is that when I run the same code in a console application it works, but on IIS not (even on the same machine)

**Edit:**
example:

There is a table MY_TABLE and a sequence MY_SEQUENCE in an oracle db.

I used the Devart Entity Developer to generate an edml model containing one entity for that table, it's called TABLE.

In the XML Editor I added the DefaultValue and the StoreGeneratedPattern attributes. it looks like this:

```
<EntityType Name="MY_TABLE">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="ID" Type="decimal" Nullable="false"                     
                devart:DefaultValue="MY_SEQUENCE.nextval"
                StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      <Property Name="COL1" Type="VARCHAR2" MaxLength="200" />
      <Property Name="COL2" Type="decimal" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
```

In my c# code it looks like this:

```
ctx.TABLEs.AddObject(new TABLE(){COL1 = "a", COL2 = 3});
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

When I execute the code in a console application, the command generated is:

```
DECLARE
  updatedRowid ROWID;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, COL1, COL2)
VALUES (MY_SEQUENCES.nextval, :p0, :p1)
RETURNING ROWID INTO updatedRowid;
OPEN :outParameter FOR SELECT ID FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ROWID = updatedRowid;
END;
```

But, the same code on IIS (on the same machine) generates this command:

```
DECLARE
  updatedRowid ROWID;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(COL1, COL2)
VALUES (:p0, :p1)
RETURNING ROWID INTO updatedRowid;
OPEN :outParameter FOR SELECT ID FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ROWID = updatedRowid;
END;
```

In old Devart versions (before 9.7) it worked well.

What may be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving to Entity Framework Version 5, and replacing the dll - Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.EF4 with Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.EF5, it started to work again.